# .NET regex to parse ifconfig

Tags: .net, regex, parsing, ifconfig

I'd like to be able to group the output of ifconfig by interface and then by inet address. Also please assume that there is no whitespace in between the interface blocks.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:12:34:56
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3456/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1382 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1344 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:247209 TX bytes:131216
          Interrupt:9 Base address:0xc000
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope: Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:109731 TX bytes:109731
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr CC:FA:00:A9:1D:7C
          inet addr:10.92.70.35  Bcast:10.92.71.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: 2001:4898:4070:101b:cefa:ff:fea9:1d7c/64 Scope: Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::cefa:ff:fea9:1d7c/64 Scope: Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:4898:4070:101b:1d4e:9b7f:f197:2e6f/64 Scope: Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:134563 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:41967 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:75871586 TX bytes:9616476
```

Would produce 3 groups that I could reference and determine if they begin with `eth` or `wlan` and then pull the `inet addr` out of each of them

So far I have `@"inet addr:(?<IpV4Address>((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))"` to get the inet address but I haven't figured out how to get the interface blocks separated.

Comment: Do you actually need to use Regex to parse the whole string? Why don't you mix a simple (simpler?) string.split and a plain old for loop?

Comment: What do you propose we split by? Keep in mind there's no standard for ifconfig's output...

Comment: Basically, you can split by new line chars (`\n`). Loop on all lines. Ignore empty lines. Each time the line starts by a space character (tab or space), "start" a new section in your parser.

Comment: Please read the question..."assume that there is no whitespace in between the interface blocks". Besides, you're talking about manual, line-by-line analysis the question asks for a regex.

Comment: Regex is **not** your goal. It's the way you think you'll achieve your actual goal, which is parsing the ifconfig format. I'm only suggesting that regex is not the only way to parse text. I'm actually convinced that using regex for this case will be overcomplicated because of the high number of portions to extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a better way to do it: determine the default interface via `$ route` and finding the interface with `Destination = default` then do `$ ifconfig default_interface` where `default_interface` is the interface you determined from `$ route`. That way there's only one interface block and you can easily parse the `inet addr`